# Chinese language codes

Tags: .net, localization, .net-2.0, cjk

We are updating an old .net 1.1 website to 2.0. The site currently supports 
Chinese (Traditional) & Chinese (Simplified)

I'm getting a run time error when trying to detect the language & culture using the codes:
zh-CHS (simified) & zh-CHT (traditional):

Please select a specific culture, such as zh-CN, zh-HK, zh-TW, zh-MO, zh-SG.

From: System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(String name)

It appears these are outdated language/culture codes.  Does anyone have any insights as to how I might map these languages to specific countries / cultures that are supported?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'd take a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.parent(VS.80).aspx

Specifically,

```
/*
This code produces the following output.

SPECIFIC CULTURE                                  PARENT CULTURE
0x0404 zh-TW Chinese (Taiwan)                     0x7C04 zh-CHT Chinese (Traditional)
0x0804 zh-CN Chinese (People's Republic of China) 0x0004 zh-CHS Chinese (Simplified)
0x0C04 zh-HK Chinese (Hong Kong S.A.R.)           0x7C04 zh-CHT Chinese (Traditional)
0x1004 zh-SG Chinese (Singapore)                  0x0004 zh-CHS Chinese (Simplified)
0x1404 zh-MO Chinese (Macau S.A.R.)               0x7C04 zh-CHT Chinese (Traditional)

*/
```

and:

> The list of cultures in the Windows
>   API is slightly different from the
>   list of cultures in the .NET
>   Framework. For example, the neutral
>   culture zh-CHT "Chinese (Traditional)"
>   with culture identifier 0x7C04 is not
>   available in the Windows API. If
>   interoperability with Windows is
>   required (for example, through the
>   p/invoke mechanism), use a specific
>   culture that is defined in the
>   operating system. This will ensure
>   consistency with the equivalent
>   Windows locale, which is identified
>   with the same LCID.

I would stick with zh-CN for the Simplified and probably just pick one of the others for Traditional - maybe most of your Traditional users are from Taiwan?

Answer (score 7):

Simplified: CN (Mainland China), SG(Singapore).
Traditional: TW (Taiwan), MO (Macau), HK (Hong Kong).

Comment: I know this is old - but hoping on hope someone could reference a source to help clarify this...